# JSONArray only returns 1 put?

Tags: arrays, json

i have a function which returns a JSON object

```
private JSONObject retrieveData()
{
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    json.put("Country", "Ireland"); 
    json.put("Capital", "Dublin"); 
    json.put("Country", "Spain");
    json.put("Capital", "Madrid");
    json.put("Country","France");
    json.put("Capital", "Paris");   


    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
    ja.put(json);

    JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();
    mainObj.put("places", ja);

    return mainObj;
}
```

my output is 
      {
      "places": [
        {
            "Country": "France",
            "Capital": "Paris"
        }
    ]
}

why aren't all the .put added to mainOBj, thanks

---

Thank you Ivo for your answer
ive just tried your solution here

```
private JSONObject retrieveData()
{
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();

    json.put("Country", "Ireland");
    json.put("Capital", "Dublin");
    ja.put(json);

    json.put("Country", "Spain");
    json.put("Capital", "Madrid");
    ja.put(json);

    json.put("Country","France");
    json.put("Capital", "Paris");
    ja.put(json);

    JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();
    mainObj.put("places", ja);

    //json.accumulate("places", list);
    return mainObj;
}
```

the same issue occurs, although 3 objects have been appended
they are the same  :-/ 
    {"places":
    [
    {"Country":"France","Capital":"Paris"},          {"Country":"France","Capital":"Paris"},{"Country":"France","Capital":"Paris"}]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `put` does is set the *key* (the first parameter) to the *value* (the second parameter). So, first you set `json.Country` to Ireland and `json.Capital` to Dublin. Next, you *overwrite* `json.Country` and set it to Spain, and continue to do so until finally, the Country and Capital are overwritten to France and Paris.

Instead of calling `put` on the JSONObject for each Country/Capital pair, you should call `put` on the JSONarray for each pair.

As was pointed out in the comments, make sure to create a new `JSONObject` before assigning the data every time.

```
private JSONObject retrieveData()
{
    // Make sure to declare both the JSONObject and JSONArray first!
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();

    // This creates one object for the Ireland/Dublin pair
    json.put("Country", "Ireland");
    json.put("Capital", "Dublin");

    // This appends above object (Ireland/Dublin pair) to the JSONArray
    ja.put(json);

    // Now repeat the above lines for each pair:
    json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("Country", "Spain");
    json.put("Capital", "Madrid");
    ja.put(json);

    json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("Country","France");
    json.put("Capital", "Paris");
    ja.put(json);

    // Finally, declare the main object and set the key "places" to
    // the array holding each pair
    JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();
    mainObj.put("places", ja);

    return mainObj;
}
```

Comment: thank your for your answer, is there a way not to overwrite and output them all?

Comment: I don't actually have the tools available to test it right now, but I think the code snippet I added should work for you.

Comment: It could be I'm missing something, but I don't see any changes in your own code besides comments. I think what he's actually missing is this line after each `ja.put` line - `json = new JSONObject();`. He wants to be operating on a new JSON object for each array element - if the JSON library is still working by references, I think you'd just be changing the original item.

Comment: Thank your Katana314 just tried your solution and it worked, now each object could be named differently for easier access for the array (e.g jsonI, jsonF, jsonS) etc

Comment: You're completely right Katana314, thanks for noticing.

Comment: would the do get function handle a post from a mobile client

if i post to the same web address as above with json format from a mobile client, will it be displayed on the servlet, thanks joshua